# Object keys in array "not a function" according to web console

Tags: javascript, loops, javascript-objects

I have a program that wants to take an input string, look for the name of a mathematical function in the input string and output the numbers also included in the input string with the found operation done to them. 
If my input looks like this:

```
1 a 2 b subtract
```

I want it to output the number 2.

Here's my code:

```
function doArithment() {
  "use strict"; 
  var i = 0;
  clearResults();
  sepNsLs();
  var found = false;
  var q = 0;
  var keys = Object.keys(operations);
  while (q < keys.length) {
    if (arrayses.letteros.indexOf(keys[q]) !== -1) {
      found = true;
      break;
    } else if (arrayses.letteros.indexOf(keys[q]) === -1) {
        q += 1;
    } 
  }
  if (found) {
    var result = arrayses.numeros[0];
    while (i < arrayses.numeros.length) {
      if (i === 0) {
        result = arrayses.numeros[0];
      } else {
        result = keys[q](result, arrayses.numeros[i]);
      }
      i += 1;
    }
```

and the global variable is declared above the function like this

```
var operations = {      
  add: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return Number(a) + Number(b);
  },
  subtract: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a - b;
  },
  multiply: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a * b;
  },
  divide: function(a, b) {
  "use strict";       
    return a / b;

  }
};
```

Now, my only problem it seems is that the web console says that keys[q] is not a function when I try to use it on this line to call the correct operation:

```
result = keys[q](result, arrayses.numeros[i]);
```

arrayses.letteros is the array of non-numbers I split in my input string and arrayses.numeros is the array of numbers. I'm new to Javascript, so I don't know if this is an issue of syntax or if Object.keys are unusable in this instance or if I need to find a way to convert the keys back from an array into their original variable form somehow.

Comment: it would be `operations[keys[q]]( ... )` ...keys is an array of key names!

Comment: Why are you using `Object.keys()` and a loop to check if the operation exists? If you have a string `inputOperation` containing `"subtract"` you can just say `if (inputOperation in operations)`. (Not clear from your code whether `arrayses.letteros` contains `"subtract"`...)

Comment: @JaromandaX thank you so much, I thought of doing that, but I didn't know I could stack square brackets like that, I wish I tried it out, you are a life-saver!

Comment: @nnnnnn I had no idea I could do that, I'm going to try that out as well as Jaromanda's, thank you so much for your help, you are the best!

Comment: The object [`.hasOwnProperty()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) is an alternative to the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in). It's worth reading up on the difference between the two.

Comment: @nnnnnn 
Sorry, lemme clarify, yes, I'm trying to find subtract or add etc. in arrayses.letteros. 
Also how would I go about modifying the loop that does the operation to the numbers in the number array if I got rid of the first loop that informs my second loop on which operation to use? This code right here:
`result = operations[keys[q]](result, arrayses.numeros[i]);`

Comment: And thank you, I'll check out hasOwnProperty, I read that it could be used with Object.keys before, but couldn't figure out how much it could affect my code.

Comment: Is `arrayses.letteros` an array or a string? If it is a string containing, say, `"subtract"` then you could say `result = operations[arrayses.letteros](result, arrayses.numeros[i]);`.

Comment: `arrayses.letteros` is an array

Comment: I should clarify that there are other objects in `arrayses.letteros` than just the operation I'm looking for, and sometimes the operation name isn't going to be there.

Comment: @nnnnn Sorry I don't know if you get notified whether or not I tag you